# iPhone/ Facebook authentication without using login dialog

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is it possible to authenticate facebook and retrive the access token by entering the user-id and password on custom login screen ?

Application will not authorise through Safari or facebook application sdk for ios.
Application requred to enter the username and password inside the application through custom login.

Hope someone help us.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you implement all the OAuth stuff yourself, then yes, it is possible. But why do you need to do something like that? Anyways, you can start inspecting the Facebook iOS SDK code if you really have to do it this way. - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk